# Lync conversations being save to another user's Conversation History

Tags: email, history, microsoft-outlook-2013, lync-2010

**Issue:**

- All of my Lync Conversations are being saved to the Conversation History folder in another user's Outlook profile.

**Workaround:**

- In the Lync window under Tools --> Options --> Personal, if I uncheck "Save IM conversations in my email Conversation History Folder" and "Save call logs in my email Conversation History folder", none of my conversations will be saved in the other user's Conversation History folder.

**Troubleshooting:**

- Last week, the same end user was having issues setting up their Automatic Replies as he was going to be out of office the next day. All I did to help was delete all of his Outlook rules after which Automatic Replies began working for him again.
- Since that day, all of my Lync conversations have been saved to his Conversation History folder.
- Since that day, I haven't had any Lync conversations saved to my Conversation History folder.
- I double-checked today, there are still no rules in his Outlook profile or mine.

Comment: Do you share the same computer? Do you share the same mailbox in outlook?

Comment: Hi LPChip, we use different computers and have our own mailboxes.

Comment: It seems to be a known issue with Lync 2010. Please take a look on the following Microsoft KB: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2689469

Answer (score -1):

u can have skype for business installed to get this resolved.
else find the regedit key
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Lync\user@domain.com\autodiscovery

find anchor mailbox and see if it is connected to the same mailbox